# Include google maps and show name at an address

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to include a simple google map to show an adress of a company. With *link* on the google-maps page it works, but only for the adress and not for the name of the company. Is there a possibility to show also the name at the adress, for example:

```
My Companyname
10 Example St    
London, Greater London WC2H 7DQ, United Kingdom
```

instead of

```
10 Example St    
London, Greater London WC2H 7DQ, United Kingdom
```

Could I create a marker with my information instead, using only plain html, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [Google Maps API 3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html), add a marker with an infowindow anchored to it, and your address details as the content in the infowindow.  [Here's a basic tutorial](http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/google-maps-api-infowindows/) I wrote.